# Building a tree from transversing an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, tree

How to build a tree from an array in PHP knowing the rules that need to be followed to build the tree?

I don't have any particular place in the code where I can find what's really wrong
Anyway, the problems are probably related with the passing by reference I'm repeatedly using.
I did not use recursion because speed is really **really** important here. From the rules that the input array has (I have full control over them), this is possible, and faster, without recursion.

How it works:
As you transverse the array, each element's ['start_order'] is a bigger number than the previous ['start_order'].
Every time that the next element's ['start_order'] is bigger than this element's ['start_order'] and the next element's ['end_order'] is smaller than this element's ['end_order'], then **that element is a child of this element**.
 After that step, I must find all the children of that element (the one I just found that it it this element's child).

Here's my code.

```
<?php
ksort($treeArray);
$tree = array();
$stack = array();
reset($treeArray);
$currentParent = &$treeArray[key($treeArray)];
$tree[] = &$treeArray[key($treeArray)];

while(next($treeArray) !== false){

    if(current($treeArray)['start_order'] <= $currentParent['end_order']){
        if(current($treeArray)['end_order'] <= $currentParent['end_order']){
            // There's a child of the previous

            // push the new parent
            $stack[] = $currentParent;

            if(!isset($currentParent['children'])){
                $currentParent['children'] = array();
            }
            $currentParent['children'][] = &$treeArray[key($treeArray)];
            $currentParent = current($treeArray);

        }else{
            // Supposed not to happen. Log the problem.
        }
    }else /* if(current($treeArray)['start_order'] > $currentParent['end_order']) */{
        // Pop the child here, there are no more children.
        if(($popedElement = array_pop($stack)) === NULL){
            $tree[] = $currentParent;
        }else{
            $popedElement['children'][] = &$treeArray[key($treeArray)];
            $stack[] = $popedElement;
            $currentParent = current($treeArray);
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Example:

The input array of this can be something that structurally looks like this:

```
[1][child1][child1child1][child2][child2child1][child2child2][child2child3][2][child2child1]
```

which resolves into this tree:

```
[1]
    [child1]
        [child1child1]
    [child2]
        [child2child1]
        [child2child2]
        [child2child3]
[2]
    [child2child1]
```

And don't forget that this order maintains. [child2child3] never appears before [child2child2], [2] never appears before [1]. In this analogy, is almost like when dealing with XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem here. The problem is related on how I treat the pass-by-reference while trying to solve this problem.

Here's the solution:

```
$tree[] = &$treeArray[key($treeArray)];
$currentParent = &$treeArray[key($treeArray)];
next($treeArray);

while(current($treeArray) !== false){

    if(current($treeArray)['start_order']['start_position'] <= $currentParent['end_order']['end_order']){
        if(current($treeArray)['end_order']['end_order'] <= $currentParent['end_order']['end_order']){
            // There's a child of the previous

            // push the new parent
            $stack[] = &$currentParent;

            $currentParent['children'][] = &$treeArray[key($treeArray)];

            $currentParent = &$treeArray[key($treeArray)];
        }else{
            // Supposed not to happen. Log the problem.
        }
        next($treeArray);
    }else /* if(current($treeArray)['start_order']['start_position'] > $currentParent['end_order']['end_order']) */{
        // Close previous element here. There are no more children.

        if(end($stack) === false){
            $currentParent = &$treeArray[key($treeArray)];
            $tree[] = &$treeArray[key($treeArray)];

            next($treeArray);
        }else{              
            $currentParent = &$stack[key($stack)];
            unset($stack[key($stack)]);
        }
    }
}
```

The main problem was actually the pass-by-reference which is different in PHP than it is in C.
To solve this problem, I'm unable to use both push or pop php functions:
The push because the $var[] operator is faster and using that function.
The pop, because its return is a copy of what I had pushed before instead of the actual element I had pushed.

Additionally, all variable assignments have to be explicitly made by reference (using the & character), so using current() for assignment is out of the question, instead I need to use the key() function like I did.

I also had a small but important bug that forced me to change the "while" instruction. It now contains current() instead of next(). That's only because after the pop of the stack I mustn't move to the next element. I need to do another iteration before I move to the next one. This solves the bad nesting generated when there are multiple tags closing in the same place.

Please note that this code is **not optimized for speed**.